# Value iteration method for matrix form error in R

Tags: r, dynamic-programming, reinforcement-learning

I want to implement the value iteration method part of neuro dynamic programming using a simple example:

```
# value iteration function
value_iteration <- function(V, P, R, gamma, tol) {
 Q <- R + gamma * P %*% V
 V_new <- max(Q)
 if (abs(V_new - V[1]) < tol & abs(V_new - V[2]) < tol) {
   return(V_new)
 } else {
   return(value_iteration(V_new, P, R, gamma, tol))
 }
}
```

```
# transition matrix and reward vector
P <- matrix(c(0.8, 0.2, 0.1, 0.9), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
R <- c(1, 0)

# discount factor and tolerance
gamma <- 0.9
tol <- 0.01

# Initial value function
V <- c(3, 2)
```

Now when I run the matrix calculations outside the function I take the result.

```
> R + gamma * P %*% V
     [,1]
[1,] 3.52
[2,] 1.89
```

but when I call the function R reports me an error.Why ?

```
 
Val <- value_iteration(V, P, R, gamma, tol)
Error in P %*% V : non-conformable arguments
```

Why is that ?What I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because V is a vector with two elements, but V_new is just a number.

P %*% V is [2x2]*[2x1] = [2x1],

but cannot compute P %*% V_new.